# Android face detection alternatives

Tags: android, camera, face-detection

I have sucesfully implemented face detection in my app using Android's `Camera.FaceDetectionListener` (following the [Android Developers guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#face-detection)), but unfortunatelly some devices does not support this feature. Is there another way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually work with OpenCV to make image processing algorithms.

http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html

Its algorithms are much better than Android face detection, besides if you download the SDK you have a faceDetection example.

**Here are the downloads:**

http://opencv.org/downloads.html

The sdk, handles camera api 2, which it works at 30 fps, with a wrapper if you want to process video frames. Besides there are samples where you can mix Java OpenCV code with JNI code, to make so much faster your algorithm.

Unfortunately, these examples are made on Eclipse projects, but they are not  difficult to merge into Android studio project.

I hope that these references are useful

Cheers.